# If I need to Erase GPT data after doing a fixpart, will it also erase all my files on that drive?

Tags: partitioning, gpt

Ubuntu 12.04 installer is not recognizing my partition,
so I searched for that problem here and found the solution in this link:

[Ubuntu installation does not recognize drive partitioning](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61939/ubuntu-installation-does-not-recognize-drive-partinioning)

So my question is
 if i need to `Erase GPT data` after doing a `fixpart`,
will it also erase all my files on that drive?

Thanks in advance for taking the time. :)

Answer (score 3):

No; `fixparts` (note the `s`; it's not `fixpart`) doesn't touch anything within your partitions, just the data structures that define them. If `fixparts` tells you that you've got leftover GPT data, and if that's the only thing you change, then `fixparts` won't even adjust your "real" partition data -- it will *only* erase the leftover GPT data. Note that I'm the author of `fixparts`, so you can consider this answer authoritative.