# Hard Drive has not enough space for installing Ubuntu

Tags: hard-drive, system-installation, windows-8, partitioning

After Windows 8 crashed on my Samsung Laptop, I decided to move on to Ubuntu as my new OS. But when I tried to install the full version i've found out that I only have a 3.0 GB space on a Hardrive that is supposed to have over 250 GB. Tried to find the hard drive with Gparted but nothing appears on it. How can I reactive my hard drive?

Thx

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your harddrive from Windows Disk Management (like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/THo5q.jpg))

Comment: @rm-vanda I fear gparted may not be useful in this case - "Tried to find the hard drive with Gparted but nothing appears on it"

Comment: Perhaps relevant: [Why can't I install Ubuntu or Wubi on a Windows Dynamic Disk?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/179215/why-cant-i-install-ubuntu-or-wubi-on-a-windows-dynamic-disk) and [Ubuntu installation does not recognize drive partitioning](http://askubuntu.com/questions/61939/ubuntu-installation-does-not-recognize-drive-partinioning)

Answer (score 0):

GParted is a great free application. You can download it [here](http://gparted.org/). You can format using that. You can also go through the Windows setup process and format the hard drive/wipe it using the restoration image on your machine or a Windows XP, VISTA, 7 or 8 disk. To me, this is a helpful web site if you are not familiar with how to go about doing the formatting process ([here](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/tipstricks/ht/format-c-from-windows-disc.htm)). After it wipes the hard drive and formats it, you can then just restart your machine and try the Ubuntu installation process again. Good luck!